# select dropdownlist value with jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to set the value of a dropdownlist with jquery. 
I've tried few solutions from the site but none of them work for my solution. 
This is what I have:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-EditContract", function () {               
            var id = $(this).data('id');
               $('#<%=ddlTsaIdEdit.ClientID%>').val(id);                
            $('#editContract').modal('show');
        });
```

Also in the backend I have code which populates the dropdown on page_load event:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();        
            dict.Clear();
            dict = util.TsaIdForContract(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString[0]));       
            ddlTsaIdEdit.DataSource = dict;
            ddlTsaIdEdit.DataTextField = "Value";
            ddlTsaIdEdit.DataValueField = "Key";
            ddlTsaIdEdit.DataBind();
            ddlTsaIdEdit.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select TSA ID --", "0"));
```

I have in the gridview action which triggers the modal popup to be shown:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                         <ItemTemplate>                                                          
                             <a style="text-decoration:none;" class="btn btn-info open-EditContract" data-id='<%#Eval("ID") %>' href="#"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></a>                                          
                         </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField>
```

Setting the values for textboxes works just fine with that method but not for dropdowns, so I would like someone to give their advice.
Also I can see the value in the source and also when I do alert(id) in JS I can see the value in a messagebox.
Every advice is welcomed.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this function:

```
function SetDropDownList(ddl, value) {
    var a = document.getElementById(dropdownlist);
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a.options[i].value == value) {
            a.selectedIndex = i;
        }
    }
}
```

And set the dropdown value like this:

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
SetDropDownList('<%=ddlTsaIdEdit.ClientID %>', id)
```

This always works for me. Also make sure you are getting a valid value for the `id`, by putting an alert, or checking in the `console.log`.

Comment: doesnt work for me, same thing :/ I can see the value with alert command @Will.i.am

Comment: Looks like some issue with dropdowlist or else. Can't say much w/o looking into both aspx & cs code...

Comment: if you have teamviewer or join.me I'll be greatly appreciate if you can connect to my pc and see whats happening. Thanks

Comment: I would have love do that. But I can't do that right at the moment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27667/discussion-between-laziale-and-will-i-am)

Comment: $('#<%=ddlTsaIdEdit.ClientID%>').val(id); this code should work. because this is how u do it

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar solution that I've implemented a few days ago.
Might be useful. I did with an HTML table with it's values, but you can use with any control of your page.

```
$("#GridViewProducts").find('tbody > tr').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('#SequenceNumber').text() == SequenceNumber) {

        $('[id*="DropDownListProductDetailCountry"]').val($(this).find('#CountryId').text());

    }
});
```

Hope this help.